# Opening a html5 pop up in flash web application

Tags: html, actionscript-3

How can I open a html5 pop up in flash web application, can we make applications which are hybrid of html5 and flash?

Comment: flash is embedded in html, so by nature all flash web applications are hybrid html/flash.  You can communicate back and forth with the html from flash by using `fscommands` (legacy) or the `ExternalInterface` class.  A quick web search will produce lots of tutorials/resources on how to accomplish this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6) to call Javascript function that would open a popup.